# Nozir who completes his vow: why different permissions in written Torah and Mishna.

Tags: korban, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, grapes-wine, hair, nozir

A nozir is forbidden grape products, haircutting and to become tomei from a dead body. 
After successful conclusion of his nezirus, he goes through a process ending with the waving of his korban as described in [Bamidbor 6 (20)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9934#showrashi=true)

> The kohen shall wave them as a waving before the Lord; it is
>   consecrated to the kohen, along with the breast of the waving and the
>   thigh of the uplifting. After this, the nazirite may drink wine.

The Torah mentions the release of only one of the prohibitions “ After this, the nazirite may drink wine.”

In the mishnah in [Nozir 6 (9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nazir.6.9?lang=bi&with=Bartenura&lang2=en) the Tanna mentions the release of two prohibitions and says

> Afterward, the nazir is allowed to drink wine and become impure
>   through contact with the dead.

The Torah only speaks about drinking wine; the mishnah includes  becoming impure through contact with the dead; neither mentions the permission to shave his head (after his hair has regrown). Why?

Comment: The Mishna is to be taken in context: See next Mishna; shaving head too early will cause a 30-day penalty. For verse 20 - verse 19 already allowed wine. Interesting that the Torah doesn't say he may become impure; maybe for brevity because some people (like a Chohen cannot.)

Comment: The reason for the prohibition of Tumah is כי נזר אלהיו על ראשו and וטמא ראש נזרו. Seemingly the reason it doesn't mention a permission to touch dead bodies in the verse is the same as why it doesn't mention haircuts. He's bald now so he couldn't cut his hair or impurify his hair even if he tried.

Comment: @DoubleAA What an interesting suggestion!